# Absolute path for list / doc items

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I get full Url of any list item/doc item when I want to pass that url through ajax email template in email body..

Comment: How do you want to get that? using jquery?

Comment: Yes that I just want to send sharepoint images and videos via mail .. for that i am using textarea column type in list..

Comment: Hey, you did not reply in my answer!

Comment: I am yet to implement that... lets see how it works.. thanks

Comment: So how it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear that how do you want to get Item/Doc absolute `URL`. As you have mentioned ajax, I can assume that you are using jQuery.

**Item URL:** You have to get default display form at first and then the full `URL` can be populated.

```
function getListItemUrl(listName, listItemId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/Forms?$select=ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=FormType eq 4",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + data.d.results[0].ServerRelativeUrl + '?ID=' + listItemId;
            return url;
        },
        error: function(data) {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

`$filter=FormType eq 4` returns all display forms.

**Document Url:** Document has read-only column named `EncodedAbsUrl`. It gives the absolute `URL` of the document. Just specify it in the `$select` query.

```
function getDocumentUrl(libraryName, documentId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + libraryName + "')/items('" + documentId + "')?$select=EncodedAbsUrl",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var url = data.d.EncodedAbsUrl;
            return url;
        },
        error: function(data) {
            return null;
        }
    });

}
```